# Count variable does not reset in javascript when re-initialized

Tags: javascript

I've encountered an odd situation. I'm building a nice little Tic-Tac-Toe game in JS, and I can't figure out why the count variable will not reset when I init() a second time.

The first game works well; the second game count does not reset to 0 even though the var count resets in init().

Game rules: game starts with X and should always start with X. You'll note that the second game starts with O.

Would anyone care to take a look? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ommcdxg/

```
var board;
var gameBoard;
var winners = [ 
                [0,1,2],
                [3,4,5],
                [6,7,8],
                [0,3,6],
                [1,4,7],
                [2,5,8],
                [0,4,8],
                [2,4,6]
];
var count;

var checkWin = function (a) {

    for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {

        if (gameBoard[winners[i][0]] === a && 
            gameBoard[winners[i][1]] === a && 
            gameBoard[winners[i][2]] === a) 
        {
            return a;
        };

    };

};

var gamePlay = function (ev) {

    console.log(ev);

    ev = ev || window.event; // browser compatibility
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement; //browser c...
    var choice = target.id; //sets a variable from the id
    choice = parseInt(choice.substring(1,2));

    // console.log(target);
    // console.log(choice);

    console.log("in gameplay " + count);

    if (count < 9) {

        if (count % 2 === 0) {

            target.innerHTML = "X";
            target.className = target.className + " x";
            gameBoard[choice] = "x";
            if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
                alert("X wins!");
                init();
            };

        } else {
            target.innerHTML = "O";
            target.className = target.className + " o";
            gameBoard[choice] = "o";
            if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
                alert("O wins!");
                init();
            };
        };

    } else {
        console.log("no more turns!");
    };

    count++;

};

var init = function () {

    gameBoard = new Array();
    xPlayer = [];
    oPlayer = [];
    count = 0;

    board = document.getElementById("board");

    if (board.hasChildNodes()) {
        board.removeChild(board.firstChild);
    };

    var b = document.createElement("b");
    board.appendChild(b);

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.className = "square";
        el.id = "t" + i;
        b.appendChild(el);
        console.log(el);
        el.addEventListener('click', gamePlay);
    };

    console.log(count);

};

init();
```

Comment: You are not really describing what is happening, so I'm guessing the issue is that `gamePlay` calls `count++` after it calls `init()`.

Comment: You're not setting the `count` variable to odd or even when you call `init` after `X` or `O` has won a game. `if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
                alert("O wins!");
                init(1 or 0 depending on who won);
            };`

Comment: You should probably try to provide a shorter code example of your problem. It would help others answering your question. And it could also help you finding the bug.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's exactly it. Two things in this code: 1) Even though I called init() from inside gamePlay after a player wins, the count++ statement still executes. 2) I was logging the count before I executed it in gamePlay, so I was always seeing count = 0 in the log even though it incremented at the end of the function. Very grateful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found 2 issues in your code:

1. As you are not breaking your code execution once user wins(`init()` is being called) **count++** will still execute
2. You need to remove the event listener once click event triggers or else your counter will still keep on increamenting but game will never finish

Try this snippet:

```js
var board;
var gameBoard;
var winners = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];
var count;
var checkWin = function(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
    if (gameBoard[winners[i][0]] === a && gameBoard[winners[i][1]] === a && gameBoard[winners[i][2]] === a) {
      return a;
    }
  }
};
var gamePlay = function(ev) {
  ev = ev || window.event; // browser compatibility
  var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement; //browser c...
  target.removeEventListener('click', gamePlay);
  var choice = target.id; //sets a variable from the id
  choice = parseInt(choice.substring(1, 2));
  console.log("in gameplay " + count);
  if (count < 9) {
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      target.innerHTML = "X";
      target.className = target.className + " x";
      gameBoard[choice] = "x";
      if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
        alert("X wins!");
        return init();
      }
    } else {
      target.innerHTML = "O";
      target.className = target.className + " o";
      gameBoard[choice] = "o";
      if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
        alert("O wins!");
        return init();
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("no more turns!");
  }
  count++;
};
var init = function() {
  gameBoard = [];
  xPlayer = [];
  oPlayer = [];
  count = 0;
  board = document.getElementById("board");
  if (board.hasChildNodes()) {
    board.removeChild(board.firstChild);
  }
  var b = document.createElement("b");
  board.appendChild(b);
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = "square";
    el.id = "t" + i;
    b.appendChild(el);
    el.addEventListener('click', gamePlay);
  }
  console.log(count);
};
init();
```

```css
#board {
  width: 400px;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.x {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.o {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still working on the finer aspects of the code, and thank you for reminding me that I have to fix the issue where a user can select the same square twice and the count will increment. Should be smooth sailing at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Felix Kling is right, it's because of the count++ at the end of gamePlay function, it's called after init().

You may return from gamePlay function right after calling init(), to fix this issue.

```js
var board;
  var gameBoard;
  var winners = [
      [0,1,2],
      [3,4,5],
      [6,7,8],
      [0,3,6],
      [1,4,7],
      [2,5,8],
      [0,4,8],
      [2,4,6]
  ];
  var count;

  var checkWin = function (a) {

   for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {

    if (gameBoard[winners[i][0]] === a &&
     gameBoard[winners[i][1]] === a &&
     gameBoard[winners[i][2]] === a)
    {
     return a;
    };

   };

  };

  var gamePlay = function (ev) {

   console.log(ev);

   ev = ev || window.event; // browser compatibility
   var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement; //browser c...
   var choice = target.id; //sets a variable from the id
   choice = parseInt(choice.substring(1,2));

   // console.log(target);
   // console.log(choice);

   console.log("in gameplay " + count);

   if (count < 9) {

    if (count % 2 === 0) {

     target.innerHTML = "X";
     target.className = target.className + " x";
     gameBoard[choice] = "x";
     if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
      alert("X wins!");
      init();
     return;
     };

    } else {
     target.innerHTML = "O";
     target.className = target.className + " o";
     gameBoard[choice] = "o";
     if (checkWin(gameBoard[choice])) {
      alert("O wins!");
      init();
     return;
     };
    };

   } else {
    console.log("no more turns!");
   };

   count++;

  };

  var init = function () {

   gameBoard = new Array();
   xPlayer = [];
   oPlayer = [];
   count = 0;

   board = document.getElementById("board");

   if (board.hasChildNodes()) {
    board.removeChild(board.firstChild);
   };

   var b = document.createElement("b");
   board.appendChild(b);

   for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = "square";
    el.id = "t" + i;
    b.appendChild(el);
    console.log(el);
    el.addEventListener('click', gamePlay);
   };

   console.log(count);

  };

  init();
```

```css
#board {
     width: 400px;
    }

    .square {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 2px solid #333;
     margin: 2px;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .x {
     background-color: blue;
     color: white;
    }

    .o {
     background-color: red;
     color: white;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

  <div id="board"></div>

  </body>
```